# The button share (like) doesn't want to update the information about page

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-sharer

The button share (like) doesn't want to update the information on page. The first time deduces the information correctly, but then, at update of page and button click the old information is deduced. I used different browsers, in them the old information is deduced.

Only after I interpose url in Object Debugger after that the page is transferred correctly. How to make so that it happened without Object Debugger ?

Example:
[enter link description here](http://www.contactimprovisation.ru/rassylka/podrobnee.php?master=434)

Answer (score 0):

But this is how it's supposed to work. Your page is not expected to change often. You are responsible for updating Facebook when you change your page.